# How do you specify the view with the new EmberJS router?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

Trying to move over to Ember 1.0.0-rc2, this I'm yet to solve (syntax below is CoffeeScript):

```
App.Router.map(() ->
  @route('EditPrices', path: '/redigera')
)
```

How would I specify that this route should use the App.Views.EditPrices.EditPricesView, rather than just App.EditPricesView? I've tried specifying 'Views.EditPrices.EditPrices' as the first parameter to the this.route() method, but this gives me absolutely nothing - no error message, no warning, but it doesn't render any content...

One incredibly ugly workaround I've come up with is this:

```
App.EditPricesView = App.Views.EditPrices.EditPricesView
```

...but clearly, there must be a better way? And please, don't tell me to put all my views in the root (App) object; that is simply not an option...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Ember expects the Views to be placed in the App root. Your workaround is the best, i can think of. The only other option would be to use [render](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_render) in the renderTemplate hook of your route, but this would require even more code:

```
App.PostRoute = App.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('myPost', {   // the view to render
      into: 'index',          // the template to render into
      outlet: 'detail',       // the name of the outlet in that template
      controller: 'blogPost'  // the controller to use for the template
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: You don't need to specify anything other than `this.render('mypost');` (if you use an unnamed outlet, render into the parent template and use the controller found by the router)

Comment: If the controller and view don't match by name, you have to do it this way.

Comment: I cannot get the `this.render('App.Views.EditPrices.EditPricesView')` approach to work, neither by specifying it as the full name nor by dropping the View suffix. Are you sure this works when there are dots in the name?

Comment: I have not tested it myself but i would suspect the String to be "Views.EditPrices.EditPrices" in this case.